# Присвоение имения переменной значения другой переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Может ли иметь место в js конструкции следующего типа:

```
var autoPlacemark;
var i = 1;
autoPlacemark[i] = 'somevalue';
```

Именно при такой конструкции сыпется ошибка `:Cannot set property '1' of undefinedCannot set property '1' of undefined`

Есть надобность циклом формировать на вывод метки, не могу разобраться как генерировать разные имена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var autoPlacemark = {}; // make an object first
var i = 1;
autoPlacemark[i] = 'somevalue';
console.log(autoPlacemark);
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто покажите `JS` куда вы хотите занести значения, ибо в вашей записи вы заносите его никуда, то есть, пытаетесь по сути значение которое равно `NULL` использовать как массив.

```
var arr = [];
var i = 1;
arr[i] = 'someValue';
```